# powersehll JSON parse to get property name

Tags: json, powershell, parsing

Need to parse this JSON file

```
{
  "domains": {
    "1.com": {
      "data_path": "c:\\zzzzz\\Domains\\1.com"
    },
    "22.com": {
      "data_path": "c:\\zzzzz\\Domains\\22.com"
    },
    "333.com": {
      "data_path": "c:\\zzzzz\\Domains\\333.com"
    },
    "4444.com": {
      "data_path": "c:\\zzzzz\\Domains\\4444.com"
    }
  },
  "domain_aliases": {}
}
```

To get the domain properties values, like

1.com
22.com
333.com
4444.com

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ConvertFrom-Json` to parse the json:

```
$json = @'
{
  "domains": {
    "1.com": {
      "data_path": "c:\\zzzzz\\Domains\\1.com"
    },
    "22.com": {
      "data_path": "c:\\zzzzz\\Domains\\22.com"
    },
    "333.com": {
      "data_path": "c:\\zzzzz\\Domains\\333.com"
    },
    "4444.com": {
      "data_path": "c:\\zzzzz\\Domains\\4444.com"
    }
  },
  "domain_aliases": {}
}
'@

$data = $json |ConvertFrom-Json
```

Then reference the `domains` property and use the `psobject` hidden memberset to enumerate its properties:

```
$data.domains.psobject.Properties |ForEach-Object Name
```